# Vertical alignement within razor view

Tags: html, css, razor

I have this snippet :

```
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.address, new { style="vertical-align: middle;" }) @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.address, new { @class = "addition ", value = "",rows="4", required = "required" })
 </p>
```

I get this result :

[image: result]

I need to put the label in the middle.
How can I change the code above to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align:middle` to text area too.

```
    <p>
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address, new { style = "vertical-align: middle;" })
           @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "addition ", style = "vertical-align: middle;", value = "", rows = "4", required = "required" })
    </p>
```